# New tag and merging: law-and-regulation ?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms

Would you think having a [law-and-regulation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law-and-regulation) could be good?

---

Law and regulation

Excerpt: Security matters which relates to law, legal actions or regulation measures.

Description:

Use this tag for question:

- Dealing with law about security (cryptographic exportation, ...)
- Dealing with specific regulations rules (Sarbanes–Oxley, ...)
- Looking for law or regulation subject

Do not use this tag:

- ??

Synonyms:

law
(legal: already a synonym of law)
regulation

Answer (score 3):

I think as we already have [law](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) and [legal](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) we probably don't need another one. We also have [compliance](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compliance) to cover the regulatory side of things.

Comment: Law and legal are already synonyms. If compliance is used for regulations, we may want to document it a few.

Comment: So "compliance" is a subset of "legal" for regulatory stuff that is only applicable to some specified organizations (e.g. banks or health care organizations?), I guess?